# AWS Lambda Dynamo update does not update the item

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

There is a DynamoDB table called Portal.
From a Lambda function written in node I want to update the `status` and `ts` fields of an item (by calling a *signalJobStart* function) and wait for the async update function to finish with a promise before continuing.
On some reason no update is happening, however no errors are raised during the operation.
There is no error in the logs, and I can see the "FINISHED" log message in the logs.

**Why there is no change made on the item in the table?
Why I cannot see neither the error nor the success message in the logs?**

(I also tried without the promise, with the same outcome. The table item does not get updated - even asynchronously.)

Here is the code from the Lambda:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-1'});

module.exports = {
signalJobStart: function(accountId, jobId) {
    console.log("Signaling job start for account %s and job %s", accountId, jobId);

    let table = "Portal";

    let params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key:{
            "accountid": accountId,
            "entity": jobId
        },
        UpdateExpression: "SET status = :s, ts = :t",
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":s": "running",
            ":t": Date.now()
        },
        ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
    };

    let updatePromise = docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    }).promise();

    updatePromise.then(function(data) {
      console.log('Success');
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

    console.log("FINISHED");
}};
```

Answer (score 5):

What helped in my case:

1. Do in async/await way:

   ```
   exports.handler = async (event) => {
   ...
   let _result = "";
   try {
      _result = await docClient.update(_updateParams).promise();
   } catch(ex){
      _result = ex;
   }
   ..
   ```
2. Make sure the field I was writing to is not a reserved word like in the following case ("data" is reserved word):

   ```
   {
   ..
   UpdateExpression: "set data = :newdata",
   ExpressionAttributeValues: {
   ":newdata": "blah"
   },
   ..
   ```

   To check this: rename column to, say, "data2" - it worked no problem.
3. Make sure you have permissions in "Execution Role" in IAM Console.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could

```
docClient.update(params).promise()
```

and then continue to use the `.then(...)` statements flow to make it work. 
Personally, I think the error handler syntax (for `update`) might not yield you a promise.

Let me know if that does not works.

Comment: Earlier I also tried it with omitting the error handler, with the same (no) result. Now I removed again, still no success. Just changed to this one: let updatePromise = docClient.update(params).promise();

Comment: can you confirm that in this new syntax `updatePromise` is NOT a promise ?

Comment: This is indeed a good lead. I just checked and it is a promise, logging out as `Promise { <pending> }` though I got a suspicion about it pending and timeouting?

Answer (score 0):

In your query `status` is **reserve keywords** and prohibited in **dynamodb**. So use `ExpressionAttributeNames` in Your query.

> Also use new Promise for handle promise

**Please check below its help you:**

```
module.exports = {
  signalJobStart: function (accountId, jobId) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log("Signaling job start for account %s and job %s", accountId, jobId);

      let table = "Portal";

      let params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key: {
          "accountid": accountId,
          "entity": jobId
        },
        UpdateExpression: "SET #status = :s, ts = :t",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          '#status': 'status'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":s": "running",
          ":t": Date.now()
        },
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
      };

      docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
          reject(err)
        } else {
          console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
          resolve({ message: 'sucsss', data: data })
        }
      })
    });
  }
};
```

> Note: Please also confirm `accountid` and  `entity` are both `Key` in you DB.

Comment: Changed as you suggested, still no success. `accountid` is primary partition key, while `entity` is the primary sort key in the table.

Comment: No error is raised. Lambda function is just finishing as normal. The final FINISHED comment is logged out. Please elaborate on `use new Promise`.

Comment: As you print `console.log("FINISHED");` its print first because its async so not wait for update. you can check what print after that.

Comment: There is nothing after that, just finishing up the lambda. It looks like the async call is pending and potentially not finishing. Just I'm not sure why there is no error on timeout.

Comment: can u please try replace you old code with my new code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181806/discussion-between-iftekhardani-and-balas).